# Discord Python Async Event Loop is Closed

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py

I have the following error when program ends.

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Code:

```
    client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    amount2 = 0
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            members.insert(amount2, member)  # or do whatever you wish with the member detail
            amount2 = amount2 + 1
    await client.close()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: `await client.close()` should be the reason why it's happening.

Comment: without that this code doesn't stop. All I need is to get members and stop this code to move forward

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't stop? the on_ready event is only ran once when the bot starts up.

Comment: I don't want bot to run all the time, I want it to only catch members and stop.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and noticed it doesn't happen while debugging, so I added a sleep(1) after the close call:

```
await client.close()
time.sleep(1)
```